# RasPi Cam - Color of image

Tags: raspicam

I've just install raspi cam and test raspistill, my first picture's colour is too yellow. Is this camera problem?

[image: sorry if image is too big but it's original]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it might be a color saturation/white-balance problem. The software will try to adjust for the available light but it doesn't always get it right. Think old web-cam or mobile phone camera. According to the [camera documentation](http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/RaspiCam-Documentation.pdf), you may want to try playing with `-sa` argument for saturation, it ranges from -100 to 100. `-awb` for white balance, try setting it `sun` or `incandescent`. (There are other options in the linked manual.)

Answer (score 1):

This is happening due to  awb_mode which is set to 'auto' by default.I was facing the same problem and when I set the awb_mode to 'fluorescent' ,the image color was quit natural.

Below is my python code:

```
from time import sleep
from picamera import PiCamera
camera = PiCamera(resolution=(1280, 720), framerate=30)
# Wait for the automatic gain control to settle
sleep(2)
camera.awb_mode = 'fluorescent'
# Finally, take several photos with the fixed settings
camera.capture_sequence(['image%02d.jpg' % i for i in range(10)])
```

Checkout the difference between the two modes:
camera.awb_mode = 'auto'
[image]

camera.awb_mode = 'fluorescent'
[image]

You may try out different modes like 'incandescent' or other as per your requirement and settings,below is the list

off: turn off white balance calculation
auto: automatic mode (default)
sun: sunny mode (between 5000K and 6500K)
cloud: cloudy mode (between 6500K and 12000K)
shade: shade mode
tungsten: tungsten lighting mode (between 2500K and 3500K)
fluorescent: fluorescent lighting mode (between 2500K and 4500K)
incandescent: incandescent lighting mode
flash: flash mode
horizon: horizon mode

However 'sun' did not work with my model of raspberry pi camera.
I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Please see the answer at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/27548/79508 .

The `--awb sun` switch to `raspstill` made the RPI camera have a more natural color.