# Green Tint Raspberry Pi Camera Outside

Tags: camera, raspicam

I am getting a green tint or full green saturation on pictures that I have taken with the Raspberry pi camera module while outside on sunny days. I am powering the raspberry pi from a battery while outside and using python to capture the images. This is not the NoIR version, it is a green board. I have cycled through a lot of the settings and do not appear to get consistent results. Here The first picture is the same with the awb setting set for sunlight and auto. I can see the clouds with no setting but it is kind of a useless picture since it is so green.

The Raspberry Pi is running raspbian jessie and is a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B.

I am going to cycle through some shutter speeds, since it was suggested with [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14047/camera-problems-green-tint-and-long-delays-after-snapshot) other post and exposure settings. Does anyone have optimal sunny outside settings they use or do you just iterate through settings to find the best one for that day?

Thanks, any pointers are appreciated!

[image: sunlight] [image: No changed setting]

Comment: Note that the No-IR version is the same as the normal one with a thin filter *removed* -- can you get any normal pics under any circumstances?

Comment: It could be the battery can't supply enough juice to the camera or high enough quality power to the camera. Try taking pictures with the Pi plugged into the mains. Is there a plastic film covering the lens of the camera?

Comment: @goldilocks I seem to be able to take pictures fine indoors but as soon as I go out on a sunny day I get this green tint

Comment: @DarthVader It is a 2500mAh battery. I'll try it plugged into a laptop or something as this is out in a field. There is not a plastic film on this one. There was a blue film on the NoIR one, which is not what I am using here.

Comment: When you take pictures indoors, are you powering the Pi from the same batteries you use when you're outdoors?

Comment: Have you been using the same batteries to power the pi indoors? maybe using a usb battery pack or an extension cord so  that we can rule out battery power as a possible cause of your green image.